# How to migrate to gulp v4 from 3?

Tags: npm, gulp

```
gulp.watch('watch', function() {
 watch('./app/index.html', function() {
  gulp.start('html');
 });
});
```

I want to run a task named 'html' when any changes to the file are made. It worked in the previous version of gulp for as for now it generates the following error.
**gulp.start is not a function**.

I can't find any way to achieve this in the newer version of the gulp. All I found that I need to change it to function, but I can't seem to find what I need to change and how?

The rest of the code is as follows

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', function(done){
  console.log("You created the default task");
  done();``
});

gulp.task('html', function(done){
  console.log('modifying the html');
  done();
});

gulp.watch('watch', function() {
 watch('./app/index.html', function() {
  gulp.start('html');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert your tasks to named functions - although that is considered best practice and is easy to do.

To fix your watch task, try:

```
gulp.watch('watch', function(done) {
 watch('./app/index.html', gulp.series('html'));
 done();  
});
```

To change to named functions:

```
function html(done) {
  gulp.src(….)
    console.log('modifying the html');
    done();
};

function watch(done) {
 watch('./app/index.html', gulp.series('html'));
 done();  
});

exports.html= gulp.series(html);
exports.default = gulp.series(watch);
```

Note that now the `watch` task is not called as a string, i.e., `'watch'`, but just `watch`.

In `exports.html`, the `gulp.series` is not strictly needed as there is only one task there so `exports.html= html;`  is sufficient.

And you only need to export a task if you wish to call it directly (as from the command line `gulp html` for example).  If say the `html` task will only be called internally by other tasks then there is no need to `export` it.

Comment: Thanks, Mark
It's not what I expected but I can't seem to describe the problem as of now. I'll get back to you when I write some more tasks and added some functionality to my code.